# Could not find class 'weka.core.FastVector',

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am using weka for my project. but get the error info"could not find class weka.core.FastVector" on the line below. I have already added weka.jar from the build path of the project by adding external jar file. How should I solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your time on reviewing my question.

```
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
FastVector      atts;
private void setUpARFF(){

         atts = new FastVector();}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that FastVector was marked as obsolete a while back, perhaps they've finally removed it.  Are you using the dev version of weka (or what version are you using)?  FastVector can be replaced with ArrayList (in dev version) so use that instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. My post maybe not clear enough. Actually the problem I met was not about FastVector class. I post another question at this linK:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399901/weka-class-cannot-be-initialized-invocationtargetexception