# Weka class cannot be initialized: InvocationTargetException

Tags: eclipse, weka

This is my first time using `weka`, I am sorry if my question seems naive. But I was really stuck by this problem.

I am using `weka` in my own `java` project in `eclipse`. I have successfully import `weka.jar` with attached `wekasource.jar`.  But when I ran the program, all the `weka` class always failed to be initialized(attribute, Fastvector etc.). All the `exceptions` are the same:

```
InvocationTargetException
```

I check the error stack where showed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/attribute

Additional Info: I tried to create a new project in eclipse ,and use weka, it works. But it still can not work in my own existing project.

Does anyone have some ideas how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have solved this weird problem. The solution is simple:

right click on the project, in the java build path, check weka.jar in order and export tab.

Hope it can help the later people who face the similar problem